# Android Home Up Button -- Specify the Parent Activity Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a Navigation Drawer on the main activity of my app with three options. Option one is the default fragment being used in the main activity. Clicking option two just replaces the old fragment with a new, but stays in the same main activity. This is all good.

Next step is that I click one of the list items in option two and it opens a new activity+fragment. I implemented the Home Up button in the new fragment with

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

The problem comes up with I hit the Home Up button. It takes me to the main activity with the initial fragment (option one) and not the option two fragment. How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `override` `onOptionsItemSelected` in Activity two and just finish it when home pressed

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

    finish();
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```